# Add extra row for overflow of text

Tags: angular, nativescript

How can I add an extra row below text in a list? I am using nativescript, but if there is a way to do it in angular, that might work too.

In my Nativescript (Angular) app, I have a list that uses RadListView. When I click on the text in each list item, the text expands. Sometimes, the larger text goes to the next line. This is a problem because RadListView does not allow the containers around the text to resize (on iOS).

So when the text goes to the next line, it gets hidden.

I could address this issue if there were an extra row below the text in each list item. That way, if the text overflows, it will just go onto the next line.

But how can I do that?

The text length varies, so this would have to be done dynamically in some way.

Example:

```
<RadListView [items]="textArray" iosOverflowSafeArea="false">
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
       <StackLayout iosOverflowSafeArea="false">
            <StackLayout style="border-width: 2; border-color: black">
                <Label [text]="item.text" textWrap="true" (tap)="makeTextBigger()"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</RadListView>

//currently, text will be hidden if it gets bigger and overflows to the next line
```

Comment: can you add some demo code on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

That's a limitation with iOS, it won't relayout the cell until requested. [Here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/expand-element-radlistview/4268/7) is a workaround.

```
var indexPaths = NSMutableArray.new();
indexPaths.addObject(NSIndexPath.indexPathForRowInSection(rowIndex, event.groupIndex));
listView.ios.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths);
```

The above code forces the list view cell to relayout.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the code in the playground from your forum link, but it is not working for me. The container does not resize. It may be because the nature of my array is structured differently than your example. Do you know if there is an array simply to add a row below the text on page load, that the text can overflow into?

Comment: It surely works, doesn't matter how your array is structured. Share your version of Playground, I may able to take a look.

Comment: Thanks but what about the original idea--is there a way to simply add an extra row?

Comment: In your playground version I can get the expansion of the container to work, but the expansion "glitches": 1) the options and cancel buttons blink and then appear, and 2) if you close the box, the buttons close too slowly so for a moment they overlap the box below. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use forceLayout soluton then you need to play with height of Label. I have updated a playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=TqcVp5).

```
  <Label [text]="country.name" class="list-group-item-heading" height="100" textWrap="true" verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%"></Label>
```

`Label` in ng0template has a predefined height `100` so on item tal when text gets bigger it does't need to re playout and textWrap works perfectly finehere.

Comment: Thanks but the reason this is non-trivial is that the height of the text in different list items varies. The solution would have to involve either (i) some way to always add an extra row to a text box or (ii) measure the text height, and then add a set amount to the height above that.